# typescript interface with function returning different types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Learning typescript and currently developing the following structure

```
type AModel {
    propA: string
}

type BModel {
    propB: string
}

class AController {
    payload():<AModel> {}
}

class BController {
    payload():<BModel> {}
}
```

Each controller must implement a payload function which returns their specific payload type. So I want something like this:

```
interface Payload {
    payload():<T>
}

class AController implements Payload {
    payload():<AModel> {}
}

class BController() implements Payload {
    payload():<BModel> {}
}
```

I'm assuming that the only way to define T is via a union type of all the different models that could be returned - or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You were close to the right path. By using generics you can achieve what you want:

Check the code in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmAPACoB8yA3gLABQyyADprgQBQCUAXMsQNy0BfWrVCRYiFAEEAsjnwQslWvQZQcDSdwDOYKKADmg4TQRY4WrckkBhHODVYs0ZMAC2DJ64jhL6bHiIZOQVyajp6RmYAjiVwiOQoCDAAVygQSkY1DW4Aci0cLwA1OCxkiBzkITjKwSA)

```js
interface Payload<T> {
  payload(): T;
}

interface AModel {
  propA: string
}

class AController implements Payload<AModel> {
    payload() {
      return { propA: 'someValue' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Toni, I missed the fact that I can type the interface with a generic.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how free you want implementations of `Payload` to be.

If `Payload` can't only hold very specific types, then you should declare a union of what those are.

But, if `Payload` doesn't care what it holds, then I think you want this:

```
interface Payload {
    payload(): unknown
}

class AController implements Payload {
    payload(): AModel {
        return { propA: 'a' }
    }
}

class BController implements Payload {
    payload(): BModel {
        return { propB: 'b' }
    }
}

new AController().payload().propA // works
```

Typescript is smart enough to know that your class returned a subtype of what's declared in the `Payload` interface, and will use that more specific type if it can.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=43&pln=24&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggsgewCYQDZQLxQN4CgoFRgBOCYMAXFAM7DECWAdgOa4C+uuokUAQoinRY8hIqTC8qtBi3a4mwCMQBmAQwDG0AAqqQqBKqQ58hMLv2GAFAEoqAV0YBrRggDujObnWpV1arABhBEY6BFRUJSh6AFswCOiIEP8dPQMjEVNzNJsqeGQ0Y1FRYghgO2JGHDEySigAclU6qA5RDg4vHz8+IJDScMiYuIgEpKgUi3STAjNUq1s+AQKMoqgSsoqqkjJJeoAjJpbCNs5GCFdA4ND+4hsAOhmJu63yKAB6V6hXBGJHaiA)

Comment: Thanks Alex, another "ah-ha" moment!